# Load environment settings from a string using Ruby's Dotenv?

Tags: ruby, environment

I have a ruby system that relies heavily on having run-time settings in the system environment (it uses capistrano 2 a lot, but also for other things), but as I need it to be much more flexible that what loading some static `.env` files can do for me, I've set up some code that generates environment configurations on the fly.

Currently the only way that I found to use those "dynamic environments" is to save them to a temporary file so that `Dotenv.load` can read them - which sounds incredibly silly to me.

I've perused the (very limited) [Dotenv documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dotenv/Dotenv/Environment) but there doesn't seem to be a call to get Dotenv to parse a string instead of a file. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the source code, I found a solution which just uses the `Dotenv` parser to read the environment text and convert it to a `Hash`, which is currently good enough for me as I can feed it to the Capistrano `run` command as an option:

```
Dotenv::Parser.call(environment_text)
```

From there, its trivial to load it into the environment for it to be available to later calls, for example:

```
Dotenv::Parser.call(environment_text).each { |k,v| ENV[k] = v }
```